# How to refactor repeated fields in a list in Coffeescript/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

The codes looks like this:

```
  $scope.markerList = [
    {
      id: 1
      pos:
        latitude: 45
        longitude: -73
      options: {animation: map.Animation.DROP}

    }
    {
      id: 2
      pos:
        latitude: 44.5
        longitude: -72.7
      options: {animation: map.Animation.DROP}
    }
    {
      id: 3
      pos:
        latitude: 44.6
        longitude: -72.6
      options: {animation: map.Animation.DROP}

    }
    {
      id: 4
      pos:
        latitude: 44.95
        longitude: -72.95
      options: {animation: map.Animation.DROP}

    }

  ]
```

As can be seen, every element of the list has the same field like`options:{...}`. Is there a simpler way to write this list in Coffeescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a `class` for the items in your list, which might look something like this:

```
class Marker
  id = 0
  constructor: (lat, long, animation) ->
    @id = ++id
    @position =
      latitude: lat
      longitude: long
    @options = 
      animation: animation
```

You would then fill your `markerList` with instances of that class:

```
defaultAnimation = map.Animation.DROP

$scope.markerList = [
    new Marker(45, -73, defaultAnimation)
    new Marker(44.5, -72.7, defaultAnimation)
    new Marker(44.6, -72.6, defaultAnimation)
    new Marker(44.95, -72.95, defaultAnimation)
]
```

Assuming that `map` is some global (or better yet, something you can inject via DI), you might even consider adding the `defaultAnimation` to the constructor which would simplify it even further:

```
class Marker
  id = 0
  constructor: (lat, lng, animation = map.Animation.DROP) ->
    ...

$scope.markerList = [
    new Marker(45, -73)
    new Marker(44.5, -72.7)
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:
(note - I edited this to fix the indentation, per the comment below.)

```
points = [
  [1, 45, -73]
  [2, 44.5, -72.7]
  [3, 44.6, -72.6]
  [4, 44.95, -72.95] ]

sml = []

for p in points
  pp = {
    id: p[0]
    pos:
      latitude: p[1]
      longitude: p[2]
    options: {animation: map.Animation.DROP} }

  sml.push(pp)

$scope.markerList = sml
```

Comment: The for loop also has an iterator `for p, i in points` so that you could use the (0-indexed) `i` for the id: `id: i + 1`. You might also consider a more descriptive destructuring assignment: `for [lat, long], i in points`. Lastly, your `sml.push(pp)` is indented one too many. Otherwise, I like it!

Comment: You're right about the indent. I tried this before I posted it, and it worked, so I probably introduced the typo somewhere in the copy process. I chose not to assume `i` was an index that could be always counted upon to be sequential with no gaps. Maybe, maybe not, but we didn't have that information. Great comment, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like that:

```
$scope.markerList = [{
  id: 1,
  pos: {
    latitude: 45,
    longitude: -73
  }
}, {
  id: 2,
  pos: {
    latitude: 44.5,
    longitude: -72.7
  }
}, {
  id: 3,
  pos: {
    latitude: 44.6,
    longitude: -72.6
  }
}, {
  id: 4,
  pos: {
    latitude: 44.95,
    longitude: -72.95
  }
}].map(function(marker) {
  marker.options = {animation: map.Animation.DROP};
  return marker;
});
```